# How to navigate to screen selected by Graphics capture picker in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-navigation

I am developing an UWP application in which i used graphics capture picker to select the window to record, but i want, when some one select window then UWP application should get minimize and that other display should come into focus

Comment: What have you tried? What's failed? Please review stackoverflow's guidelines for posting questions.

Comment: Do you have any progress? You could mark useful answer, which will help others that facing same question to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the user minimizes a uwp app or switches to another app, this uwp app will be suspended. Besides, GraphicsCapturePicker control must be called from a UI thread, which means it will prevent the GraphicsCapturePicker control from appearing if the uwp app is minimized.

Therefore, I have to say that there is no way could implement your requirement.